# Question about differential amplifier

Tags: amplifier, bjt, differential

why is there 0.7V instead of 1.2V on the common emitter?

[image: BJT]

if you go through Q1 mesh : Ve = 0.5+Vbe = 1.2 instead of Ve = 0+Vbe = 0.7 from Q2.

Comment: Why do you think there should be 1.2 V?  Please show your math for this.

Comment: Q1,2 are in parallel, not series

Comment: if you go through Q1 mesh : Ve = 0.5+Vbe = 1.2 instead of Ve = 0+Vbe = 0.7 from Q2

Comment: Will Q1 or Q2 determine the voltage at the common emitters?  Either transistor can determine that voltage.  Which one wins the fight?

Comment: Starting with the voltage on the Q2 base, what is the voltage at the two emitters?  Now, what is the voltage across the Q1 base-emitter junction?  Pay attention to which way the emitter arrow is pointing.

Comment: Vc1 is at -5V so there is no current through Q1. As would be expected since Q2 base is at a more negative voltage than Q1 base.

Comment: At 0.058 volts per decade of current thru a diode, the current thru left-hand transistor is 10^(0.500 / 0.058) or about 9 orders of magnitude smaller than the current thru the right-hand emitter-base junction.

Comment: i know that is 0.7 in emitter. My question more precisely is: Why do i need to go through Q2's mesh instead of Q1? If i take Q1's mesh and Ve = 1.2V so Veb2 >=0.7 and Veb 1>=0.7. So Q1 is not cutoff. Its a silly question but i really dont know.. Do i need to do like this guy? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RH67Rn2zZ4 Time: 19:47

Comment: In a differential arrangement like this one of the transistors "wins" and the other loses. One turns on and the other off (more or less, in each case).| For a given Ve, If BOTH were on the current drawn will increase lowering Ve until one turns off and the other doesn't. The one which turns off first is the one with less base drive. Which one is that here? Once one ois off the other sets the operating point of Ve (essentially).

Comment: Russell McMahon thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSwd1I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You know that the emitter voltage for both BJTs is the same (they are tied together.) It follows from the schematic that \$\mid\: V_{\text{BE}_2}\mid\:\:=\:\:\mid V_{\text{BE}_1}\mid+500\:\text{mV}\$. You should be able to easily see that fact, directly from the schematic: \$V_{\text{B}_1}=V_{\text{B}_2}+500\:\text{mV}\$ and \$V_{\text{E}_1}=V_{\text{E}_2}\$.

Since you also know that for every \$60\:\text{mV}\$ difference in \$V_\text{BE}\$ there will be about \$10\times\$ the collector current, it follows that \$\frac{I_{\text{C}_2}}{I_{\text{C}_1}}\approx e^{^\frac{500\:\text{mV}}{26\:\text{mV}}}\approx 225\times10^{6}\$. In other words, \$Q_2\$ hogs all available current in \$R_1\$. What remains for \$Q_1\$ is in the small "parts per billion." (In short, nothing at all.)

From here, you have to only decide the approximate collector current for \$Q_2\$. If you temporarily assume that \$V_{\text{BE}_2}=700\:\text{mV}\$ then you find that \$I_{\text{C}_2}=\frac{5\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}\approx 4.3\:\text{mA}\$. Since this value is fairly consistent with \$V_{\text{BE}_2}\approx 700\:\text{mV}\$ for most small-signal BJTs, you can reasonably rest on this computed value.

This assumption confirmed, the result is easily worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Redraw the diagram with Q1 and Q2 emitter- base paths replaced by diodes, D1 and D2. D1 has 0.5V applied to its cathode, and D2 has 0V applied to its cathode. A diode will drop 0.7V when it's on.

Given the above, only one on/off configuration of diode states, out of four possibilities, can occur.